# Why are my panels not showing up in the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, visibility

```
public class InputPanel extends JPanel{
    public static int shapeType; //1: Rectangle; 2: Oval; 3: Line
    public static boolean isFilled; //whether or not the shape is filled
    public static Color color; //color of the shape

    public InputPanel(){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));

        JButton rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
        JButton oval = new JButton("Oval");
        JButton line = new JButton("Line");
        JRadioButton fill = new JRadioButton("Filled:");
        JButton color1 = new JButton("Color..");

        rect.addActionListener(new rectListener());
        oval.addActionListener(new ovalListener());
        line.addActionListener(new lineListener());
        isFilled = fill.isSelected();
        color1.addActionListener(new colorListener());

        panel.add(rect);
        panel.add(oval);
        panel.add(line);
        panel.add(fill);
        panel.add(color1);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}



public class PaintPanel extends JPanel{

    public static int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    ArrayList<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public PaintPanel(){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            PaintPanel.x1 = e.getX();
            PaintPanel.y1 = e.getY();
        }

        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            PaintPanel.x2 = e.getX();
            PaintPanel.y2 = e.getY();
            if(InputPanel.shapeType == 1){
                shapeList.add(new Rectangle(PaintPanel.x1, PaintPanel.y1, PaintPanel.x2, PaintPanel.y2, InputPanel.isFilled));
            }
            if(InputPanel.shapeType == 2){
                shapeList.add(new Oval(PaintPanel.x1, PaintPanel.y1, PaintPanel.x2, PaintPanel.y2, InputPanel.isFilled));
            }   
            if(InputPanel.shapeType == 3){
                shapeList.add(new Line(PaintPanel.x1, PaintPanel.y1, PaintPanel.x2, PaintPanel.y2));
            }
            repaint();
        }
      });

     this.setVisible(true);   
    }

    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(Shape s : shapeList){
            s.draw(g);
        }
    }

}

public class PaintGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shape Drawer!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new InputPanel());
        frame.add(new PaintPanel());

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I'm positive I've created the JFrame properly and all of my other classes work, but there must be something in here I'm missing...
When I run the main method all I get is a gray box that is clearly a square (500x500, as instantiated in the PaintPanel class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I am having a hard time finding `JFrame` in your code. Why are you doing `setVisible(true)` on your panels?

Comment: I added the JFrame and i set it to true messing around to try to solve the problem of the panels not showing up

Comment: `frame.add(new InputPanel()); frame.add(new PaintPanel());`  The default layout for frame will take only one component with no constraint.  Change it to something like `GridLayout(1,0)`

Comment: 1.  class PaintPanel here in the class you create one more panel which is not added to the this panel add following statement
this.add(panel);

2.InputPanel : Same as above
this.add(panel);

Finally you did not set LayoutManage for JFrame as well as JPanel 
So You need to set it also

Comment: Add For Both Panel
GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();
gb.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panel.add(rect,gb);
panel.add(oval,gb);
panel.add(line,gb);
panel.add(fill,gb);
panel.add(color1,gb);
this.add(panel);

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what Andrew mentioned, I noticed that within both your *InputPanel* and *PaintPanel* you're creating a new JPanel. You're adding new components to this panel, for sure, but at the end you're not adding this JPanel itself to your *InputPanel* or *PaintPanel*. So, make sure that in your constructors for these panels you have a `add(panel)`  at the end.

Also, as a side note, do please keep in mind that most operations in Swing are not thread-safe and so read about ["Concurrency in Swing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) before creating/interacting with UI components. In other words, any updates to the user interface must happen on the event dispatch thread, like the start-up of your application:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shape Drawer!");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //set the layout, add your panels

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);             
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JFrame by default uses BorderLayout.

```
frame.add(new InputPanel());
frame.add(new PaintPanel());
```

is equivalent to saying,

```
frame.add(new InputPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(new PaintPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The net result being that the Panel that is added last would be the one that is visible, provided the rest of your code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Must add the panel to the frame, use:

```
this.add(panel);
```